# Controlling MSP430 with Android Mobile USB

Tags: embedded, usb, msp430, texas-instruments

I'm looking to control a bunch of LEDs from my Android phone, with a TI MSP430 or similar.I want to communicate vis USB. The MSP430 has a USB port, but I can't find any information about using the USB port for anything besides programming the chip. Is there a way around this, to use USB to communicate with the board?

Comment: I suspect they are both "slave" USB ports, so they probably can't be connected to each other.

Comment: Which MSP430 are you talking about? Maybe the Launchpad?

Comment: Turbo J actually i have to interface ADS1192 kit with Android Mobile via USB ,This kit has MSP430 and has USB port with which we can connect to PC.I want to check how i can connect Android Phone with USB interface.

Comment: Some (but by no means all) Android phones can function as USB hosts.  You'd first want to figure out how to use the MSP430 board with a PC, then translate what you have learned to the Android USB host APIs

Comment: Have you considered using a an FTDI UART to USB chip on your hardware and using a project such as this for android https://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/ .It saves you writting horrible USB drivers and gives you the flexibility and option to connect to a PC application or ternminal if needed

Comment: @gcb - it's likely that any MSP430 varient with a USB port has example firmware which implements CDC-ACM and would be usable with the above project (and of course with a PC) without needing to add an additional chip.  Of course, if the part chosen doesn't have a USB peripheral, then a physical USB serial converter would be needed.